# about removeClass from parent element

Tags: jquery, parent, removeclass

I'm tried to build the effect like this: click .labelElment to change itselvse size, and click another block or a.close to recovery .labelElment's size.

take look the html:

```
<div id="labelGroup">
        <div  class="labelElement c1">
            <div class="panel">
                <span class="avatar"></span>
                  <ul class="labelGroup">
                    <li class="l1">Label 1</li>
                    <li class="l2">Label 2</li>
                    <li class="l3">Label 3</li>                
                  </ul>
             </div>
             <div class="info">
                 <ul>
                     <li>Information</li>
                     <li><a href="###" class="close">close</a></li>

                 </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div  class="labelElement c2">Block</div>    


    </div>
```

And jquery code:

```
$('#labelGroup').delegate( '.labelElement', 'click', function(){

 $('.labelElement').removeClass('s1')
 $(this).addClass('s1');
 $('#labelGroup').isotope('reLayout');
});

$('.close').click( function(e){
        $(this).parents(".labelElement").removeClass("s1");
 });
```

in the .delegat(), removeClass work well, but in the .click(), it doesn't work, so what's the problem?

Comment: Any console messages? Tried adding log lines? And why is your link to `###`?!

Comment: is the click event called

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$(this).closest('.labelElement').removeClass("s1");
```

Comment: Guesses are not answers. Try posting as a comment in future, and make an answer if it works.

Comment: Adding comments link is not enabled for me as I am a new user .

Comment: In that case I recommend trying your suggestion first (jsfiddle is highly recommended) so that you can be more certain. When you have enough rep, you can post quick suggestions when it is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Your click is bubbling up the DOM hierarchy, thus also triggering the click event on .labelElement and re-adding the just removed class.

Use e.stopPropagation() to prevent bubbling.

https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation

Or see answer to this question:

[.parents().removeClass() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843472/parents-removeclass-not-working?rq=1)