# jQuery parent(); function removeClass(); not working (bug)

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, parent

I have a portfolio where I list portfolio items.
I have classes so when you click the item, it has an effect. 
For some reason, when I click the minus button, it doesn't remove the class 'on'.

Here is the jQuery:

```
  $('.portfolio-item').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('on');
  });
  $('.minus').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.portfolio-item').removeClass('on');
  });
```

and here is the element set up:

```
<div class="portfolio-item" style="margin-top: 5px; ">
   <div class="overlay">
      <h1>LOW POLY ISLANDS</h1>
      <h3>LOW POLY</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="about">
      <h1>LOW POLY ISLANDS</h1>
      <h3>LOW POLY</h3>

      <div class="descrip">
         This is a low poly island make in Blender and edited in Photoshop.
      </div>

      <div class="minus"></div>
      <div class="plus"></div>
    </div>
    <img src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/max_1200/57909c29180525.55fc4b1875c26.png" width="100%" />
</div>
```

How do I fix this - I want to be able to remove the class 'on' when I click on 'minus'.

Comment: Are the elements with the `minus` class added dynamically....perhaps by clicking the element with the `plus` class? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: No the minus class is made in css and I manually insert the element for it.

Comment: WHat do you mean "I manually insert the element for it."? Are you adding the element with the `minus` class after the page loads?

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem at JSFiddle?

Comment: Use `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.  No, it is already inserted.

Comment: @AlexSafayan Good luck. Your last name is similar to me. ha ha ha

Comment: @alirezasafian Hahaha are you Iranian?

Comment: @AlexSafayan Yup. why?

Comment: @alirezasafian Oh I was just wondering. I'm Iranian, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you click your `minus` it removes the class `on`. However, at the same time, as `minus` is located within `portfolio-item`, it triggers its `click` event and applies this class back.

You can use `e.stopPropagation()` to disable this behaviour.

According to documentation, **[`e.stopPropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)**

> prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Here is the working [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/cjsm1onh/). It looks awful, but demonstrates the functionality.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use **e.stopPropagation()**

```
$('.minus').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('.portfolio-item').removeClass('on');
  });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/oe5p9n8u/)